# Converting CoreMotion Portrait Angles to Landscape Right and Landscape Left in Objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, quaternions, core-motion

I am trying to get CoreMotion to behave correctly when the user's device is in Landscape Mode. The below code is working for Portrait mode but I can't figure out how to convert it to Landscape Left and Landscape Right. If you are familiar with Quaternions and CoreMotion, any help would be hugely appreciated.

**The Problem:**
There is a ScrollView which contains an image view, this image view can only be partially seen at any given point, and is revealed when the user rotates their phone to aim at it. Imagine sitting in the front row of a movie theater and turning your head in all directions to see the entire screen.

I am using a quaterion for the yaw variable because the true 'yaw' from the attitude seems to be for if the phone was being held flat.

When turning the phone in either landscape mode, I need to know the quaterion equations to calculate the correct degrees for the image and the device.

```
    // set content offset for image inside scrollview
    CGFloat offsetX;
    if (self.deviceDegreesZ >= 180) {
       offsetX = (_maximumXOffset/2) + (_maximumXOffset/2) * (fabs(self.deviceDegreesZ - 180))/90;
    } else {
       offsetX = (_maximumXOffset/2) - (_maximumXOffset/2) * (fabs(self.deviceDegreesZ - 180))/90;
    }

     CGFloat offsetY;
     if (self.deviceDegreesY >= 90) {
         offsetY = (_maximumYOffset/2) + (_maximumYOffset/2) * (fabs(self.deviceDegreesY - 90))/45;
     } else {
         offsetY = (_maximumYOffset/2) - (_maximumYOffset/2) * (fabs(self.deviceDegreesY - 90))/45;
     }

    if (offsetX != 0 && offsetY != 0) {
        [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(offsetX, offsetY) animated:NO];
    }


    // device angles used to set content offset above and look at imageview
    // Quaternion
    CMQuaternion quat = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
    int thePitch = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch * (180.0 / M_PI);
    int theRoll = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll * (180.0 / M_PI);
    int theYaw = radiansToDegrees(asin(2*(quat.x*quat.z - quat.w*quat.y)));

    // gravity
    CMAcceleration gravity = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.gravity;
    double rotation = atan2(gravity.x, gravity.y) - M_PI;
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);

    // portrait (working)
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){

        // X
        if (quat.y >= 0.5f) {
            self.deviceDegreesZ = radiansToDegrees(asin(2*quat.x*quat.y + 2*quat.w*quat.z));
        } else if (quat.y <= -0.5f) {
            self.deviceDegreesZ = 360 + radiansToDegrees(asin(2*quat.x*quat.y + 2*quat.w*quat.z));
        } else {
            self.deviceDegreesZ = 180 - radiansToDegrees(asin(2*quat.x*quat.y + 2*quat.w*quat.z));
        }

        // Y
        CMAcceleration gravity = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.gravity;
        if (gravity.z >= 0) {
            self.deviceDegreesY = thePitch; // - abs(theYaw)
        } else {
            self.deviceDegreesY = 180.f - thePitch; //  - abs(theYaw)
        }
    }

    // landscape left
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        // ???
    }

    // landscape right
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        // ???
    }
```